# How open a url with http authentication in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, http, http-authentication, delphi-5

How open a url (**a browser window**) that need "http authentication" passing login and password in a transparent way? The legacy app in delphi need open a report in ".aspx" from Reporting Services.

Thanks, Celso

Answer (score 5):

Use the Indy TidHTTP component as it can easily handle the authentication requirements.  Drop the component on the form and:

```
IdHTTP1.Request.UserName := 'xxx';
IdHTTP1.Request.Password := 'xxx';
IdHTTP1.Get(x);
```

I believe that works for whatever Indy version that you might have.

Comment: You can use Indy with Delphi 5.  I do.

Comment: There is a BasicAuthentication property (boolean) in IdHTTP too, which I would set to true to make the code more self-explaining

Comment: have a way to put TidHTTP in Delphi 5 without install "component", maybe using only generate the units?

Comment: You don't necessarily need to install the visual components to use Indy as long as the source is in your project, or library path.  You could also look at Synapse if you want an even lighter weight choice.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [WinHTTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384273%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), check the [`IWinHttpRequest.SetCredentials`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method

check this sample

```
uses
  Variants,
  SysUtils,
  WinHttp_TLB;


Const
  HTTPREQUEST_SETCREDENTIALS_FOR_SERVER = 0;
Var
  Http: IWinHttpRequest;
begin
  try
   Http := CoWinHttpRequest.Create;
   try
     Http.Open('GET', 'http://Foo.com/home', False);
     Http.SetCredentials('AUser','APassword', HTTPREQUEST_SETCREDENTIALS_FOR_SERVER);
     Http.Send(EmptyParam);

     //Do your stuff

   finally
     Http:=nil;
   end;
  except
    on E:Exception do
      Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: No, because WinHttp (Windows HTTP Services) is part of Windows.

Comment: this "http.open" literally will open a browser? because i need this

Comment: No, this component is for retrieve the content of a web page or download a http resource.

Answer (score 1):

you can just have an URL with the username and password in it if that is acceptable.

http://username:password@www.mysite.com/page.aspx

Comment: firefox cool (despite warnings that it does)...but in ie does not works

Comment: By default IE does not support it. Have a look here how it can be changed: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834489

Comment: I would not recommend sending your password as plain text in a URL.

Comment: This is not in the HTTP RFC standard either, more something "exotic"

Comment: @mjn: no, it is not in the HTTP spec, because the "http" URL scheme is not actually part of HTTP itself. The general format of a URL is defined separately in RFC 3986 instead, which does define the use of username and password in URLs (see section 3.2). Anyone who parses an "http" URL (ie a webbrowser or other HTTP client) is supposed to separate the URL into its individual components and then send an HTTP request with a proper 'Authorization' header.

Comment: @Remy the HTTP 1.1 spec http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-3.2.2 defines the http URL as `http_URL = "http:" "//" host [ ":" port ] [ abs_path [ "?" query ]]` - so I am confused now :)

Comment: @mjn: I did not see the URL definition in RFC 2616 before. Looking at it, I see that RFC 2616 section 3.2.1 say: _For definitive information on URL syntax and semantics, see "Uniform Resource Identifiers (URI): Generic Syntax and Semantics," RFC 2396 (which replaces RFCs 1738 and RFC 1808). This specification adopts the definitions of ... "authority" from that specification._ The `authority` component defined in RFC 2396 (replaced by RFC 3986) section 3.2 allows for a `userinfo` component. That is where a "user:pass" pair would be used. The definition in RFC 2616 section 3.2.2 is incomplete.

Comment: @mjn: ... I have seen plenty of working uses of HTTP URLs that conform to the RFC 2396/3986 definition to allow the `userinfo` component. The RFC 2616 definition does not allow the `userinfo` component, but it also does not really the follow the RFC 2396/3986 definition, which is generic and more commonly used.

Comment: @Remy thank you for clarifying! It looks like the German Wikipedia entry about [http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL](URL) is wrong: an example of a http URL with user/pass warns that this is not a valid URL, and links to http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-3.2.2 as a reference. In the English Wikipedia, this warning is missing.

Comment: He asked a question and I gave an answer with the "if acceptable" to solve his problem. Would have been pointless to tell him to re-code his legacy code and create a secure WebService etc etc. He asked how he open a link that need authorization in a transparent way rather than secure